# Scroll to bottom of div when tab is inactive

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that has items added to it on a periodic basis. I'm scrolling to the bottom of the div using

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("infoWindow");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

But this only works when the tab is active. How can I do this so it auto scrolls when a user is browsing another tab?

Comment: what's the point of scrolling if the user is not seeing ? Wouldn't be better to go to the bottom completely, when the user set the tab as active again?

Comment: Because the user might miss information when he goes back to the tab again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it took me quite some time to find this workaround, however I'm using Bootstrap and the shown.bs.tab-event seems to be a specific event only used in Bootstrap... but maybe it gives you a hint in the right direction and you will find a similar solution/event in js:

Like Gonzalo said above it should be enough to scroll to the bottom after the tab is set to active.
So when I activate tab2 the shown.bs.tab-event fires and scrolls my div 'messages' down to the bottom.

```
$('a[href="#tab2"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('messages');
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
});
```